# if the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$, when $a$ is between $0$ and $1$. how would we prove that the sequence $\{(a_n)^n\}$ converges to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

if the sequence converges to a then how do I prove the sequence to the $n$th power converges to $0$. I have tried a couple of basic methods but I don't seem to have made any progress

Comment: what did you try exactly?

Comment: Don't say "$a$ is between $0$ and $1$." This is imprecise: can $a$ be $0$ or $1$? Say rather: $0<a<1$, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Just because the statement is wrong in case $a=1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $0<a<1$ then we can find some $\epsilon>0$ such that $0<a-\epsilon<a<a+\epsilon<1$. From the definition of limit it follows that there is some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a-\epsilon<a_n<a+\epsilon$ for all $n\geq n_0$. This implies $0<(a_n)^n<(a+\epsilon)^n$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Since $0<a+\epsilon<1$ we have $(a+\epsilon)^n\to 0$. Now just use the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, there exists $N_0$ such that $n\geq N_0$ implies

$$|a_n-a|<\frac{1-a}{2}$$

Then for $n\geq N_0$ we have

$$a_n<a+\frac{1-a}{2}=\frac{1+a}{2}<1$$

In much that same manner as above, there exists $n\geq N_1$ such that

$$|a_n-a|<\frac{a}{2}$$

Then for $n\geq N_1$ we have

$$a_n>a-\frac{a}{2}=\frac{a}{2}>0$$

Take $N_2=\max\{N_0,N_1\}$. For $n\geq N_2$ we have

$$0<\frac{a}{2}<a_n<\frac{1+a}{2}<1$$

Now, let $\epsilon>0$ be given and define

$$N=\max\left\{N_2,\left\lceil \frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln\left(\frac{1+a}{2}\right)}\right\rceil\right\}$$

Then we have

$$0<(a_n)^n<\left(\frac{1+a}{2}\right)^n\leq \left(\frac{1+a}{2}\right)^N\leq \left(\frac{1+a}{2}\right)^{\left\lceil \frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln\left(\frac{1+a}{2}\right)}\right\rceil}$$

$$\leq \left(\frac{1+a}{2}\right)^{\frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln\left(\frac{1+a}{2}\right)}}=e^{\ln(\epsilon)}=\epsilon$$

This implies that for $n\geq N$ we have

$$|(a_n)^n-0|=|(a_n)^n|=(a_n)^n<\epsilon$$

By definition, we conclude that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^n=0$$